Communicate with Bot framework through web api
I have a bot builder setup and a web api for it in asp.net C#. like this:
// This ASP Controller is created to handle a request. Dependency Injection will provide the Adapter and IBot
    // implementation at runtime. Multiple different IBot implementations running at different endpoints can be
    // achieved by specifying a more specific type for the bot constructor argument.
    [ApiController]
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly IBot _bot;

        public BotController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
            _bot = bot;
        }

        [HttpPost, HttpGet]
        [Route("api/messages")]
        public async Task PostAsync()
        {
            await _adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot);
        }


        // Health check endpoint
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("health")]
        public IActionResult HealthCheck()
        {
            // Implement your availability check logic here
            bool isApiAvailable = CheckAPIAvailability();

            if (isApiAvailable)
            {
                return Ok("API is available");
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(503, "API is unavailable");
            }
        }

        private bool CheckAPIAvailability()
        {
            // Implement your logic to check API availability here
            // This could involve checking database connections, external dependencies, etc.
            // For simplicity, let's return true if the API is running
            return true;
        }

    }

when i send request like this:
var payload = new
            {
                type = "conversationUpdate",
                membersAdded = new[]
                {
                    new { id = "bot1", name = "Bot 1" },
                    new { id = "user1", name = "User 1" },
                },
                membersRemoved = new object[0],
                channelId = "test",
                conversation = new { id = "conversation1" },
                recipient = new { id = "bot1", name = "Bot 1" , role="bot"},
                from = new { id = "user1", name = "User 1", role="user" },
                locale = "en-US",
                id = "conversation1",
                //serviceUrl=

            };
            string jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.Indented);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"http://localhost:5000/api/messages", content);

what should i provide for serviceUrl? should it be the smae as "http://localhost:5000/api/messages"?
i tried to use this value for the serviceUrl in the body of the json posted to my web api:
serviceUrl= "http://localhost:5000/api/messages"

but i got this error from the api.
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Mon, 13 May 2024 11:04:51 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Content-Length: 0
}}

and when i looked at the logger in the console, i see this error happened:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN3J7I0HVPRG", Request id "0HN3J7I0HVPRG:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
         at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CloudAdapterBase.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at PteroBotWebAPI.AdapterWithErrorHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\ProMate\Source\PetroBot\PteroBotWebAPI\AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs:line 30
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CloudAdapterBase.ProcessActivityAsync(AuthenticateRequestResult authenticateRequestResult, Activity activity, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CloudAdapterBase.ProcessActivityAsync(String authHeader, Activity activity, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.CloudAdapter.ProcessAsync(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse, IBot bot, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at PteroBotWebAPI.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync() in D:\Projects\ProMate\Source\PetroBot\PteroBotWebAPI\Controllers\BotController.cs:line 43
         at lambda_method6(Closure , Object )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

how can i solve the issue? how can i send request to my bot and get my bot response through my asp.net web api?
UPDATE:
I tried to set this:
serviceUrl= "http://localhost:5000/api/response"

and added a route to my api like this:
// Endpoint to handle any routes starting with api/response
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/response/{*path}")]
public async Task HandleBotResponseAsync()
{
    // what should be here?!
}

i see bot sends it response to this method now but i don't know how to send response then back to user issued the first request to this api

Try this as serviceUrl: serviceUrl= "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/teams/"

did not work. actually the serviceUrl is used by bot to send its response into it. when using bot emulator, it starts a port and sends that address as serviceUrl so bot sends back answer to that address. i want to have my own setup which i can send and receive message back and forth with my bot. i wonder how can i make my bot sends back response through the same api i send message into
